# Django test field that slug is created from

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a `test` for `UpdateView` of `Model` which has a `title` and `slug`. When I try to `test` my `view` I can't recive a `response` because `save` method throws an

**ERROR**

```
Reverse for 'books-delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<slug>[^/]+)$']
```

I understand that slug can not be empty and that's what I try to test. So step by step:

**MODEL**

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**TEST**

```
class BookUpdateTest(TestCase):
    
    def test_book_must_have_title(self):
        """Create book object and updates fields with wrong data"""

        book = Book.objects.create(title='Camera Work 2')

        response = self.client.post(
             reverse('books-update', kwargs={'slug': book.slug}), {'title': '',})
        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**UPDATE VIEW**

```
class BookUpdateView(UpdateView):             
    model = Book                              
    fields = '__all__'                        
    success_url = '/'                         
    template_name = 'books/book_update.html'
```

**URL PATTERNS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<str:slug>', BookUpdateView.as_view(), name='books-update'),
    path('delete/<str:slug>', BookDeleteView.as_view(), name='books-delete')
]
```

How the test for `title` field should look like?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? A simple `print(book.slug)` would probably suffice after you call `create()`

Comment: The error looks like it's coming from a call to `reverse` or a `{% url %}` tag for a path named "books-delete"

Comment: Yes, but the error is thrown just because `slug` can not be an empty string and when I try to update 'title' I receive an `ERROR` instead of the `response` so I can't just check the response code. What I'm looking for is the way to test that case.

Comment: Is there a link to "books-delete" in the template used by the update view? I don't think that error would be caused by the save method

Comment: The only `books-delete` link is defined in `url_patterns` so I haven't defined it in template.

Comment: I have updated the post with my `UpdateView` and `url_patterns`.

Comment: There must be a url tag in "book_update.html" (or a template it extends) for "books-delete", there is nowhere else that makes sense unless you are looking at the wrong test

Comment: Is there any chance this is happening because of ```slug``` because it is a path converter in Django. See (this)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters]. Try changing the ```slug``` field name to something else.